# Equivalent of summarise_all for group_by and slice

Tags: r, group-by, na

I'm currently using group_by then slice, to get the maximum dates in my data. There are a few rows where the date is `NA`, and when using `slice(which.max(END_DT))`, the NAs end up getting dropped. Is there an equivalent of `summarise_all`, so that I can keep the NAs in my data?

```
ID Date         INitials
1  01-01-2020   AZ
1  02-01-2020   BE
2  NA           CC
```

I'm using

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(Date))
```

I need the final results to look like below, but it's dropping the NA entirely

```
ID Date        Initials
1  02-01-2020  BE
2  NA          CC
```

Comment: Reproducible example? It's not entirely clear to me what you want.

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: Did you convert the `Date` column to a `Date` class? If not, `which.max()` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`which.max()` is not suitable in this case because (1) it drops missing values and (2) it only finds the first position of maxima. Here is a general solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m-%d-%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(Date == max(Date) | all(is.na(Date)))

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   ID [2]
#      ID Date       INitials
#   <int> <date>     <fct>   
# 1     1 2020-02-01 BE      
# 2     2 NA         CC
```

---

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L), Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
NA), .Label = c("01-01-2020", "02-01-2020"), class = "factor"), 
INitials = structure(1:3, .Label = c("AZ", "BE", "CC"), class = "factor")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's dropping the NA because you're asking it to find the max date...which NA would not fall into. If you want to go the "which.max" route, then I'd just run the dataset again, using filter, and grab the NA(s) and bind them to the dataset.

```
    df.1 <- df%>%
    filter(is.na(Date))

    df <- rbind(df, df.1)
```